# Syntastic check not working when using arguments

Tags: vim, syntastic

I setup Syntastic to validate my PHP code. I'm using PHP, and PHPCS as checkers.

```
let g:syntastic_php_checkers = ['php', 'phpcs']
```

This works perfectly. However, I want to use the WordPress coding standards, so I added this line

```
let g:syntastic_php_phpcs_args = "--standard=WordPress"
```

It should pass the standard argument. It's worth noting, that this argument work in the command-line. However, when I run "SyntasticCheck" on Vim, I get no response. Not even an error notice.

Something is going on?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass in the default arguments for `g:syntastic_php_phpcs_args` as well as your additional configuration options. The default options are `--report=CSV`, so your vim command should be:

`let g:syntastic_php_phpcs_args="--report=csv --standard=WordPress"`

FWIW, I found this looking at the phpcs.vim file in Syntastic.